# PrettyPhoto with Facebook comments

Tags: facebook-comments, prettyphoto

Hi I am trying to implement prettyphoto for my own site (non CMS).
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Out of the box there is a tweet and like button on the image viewer. I wish to implement Facebook comments instead, with the ability to comment on each individual picture.

My JS coding skills are somewhat "limited", so advice would be greatly appreciated on how to achieve this goal :)

If any added file or information is needed, please do tell and I will provide asap!

Thanks for your help in advance!

I found in the prettyphoto javascript that is for the "social" stuff:

```
 social_tools:'<div class="facebook">
 <script src="connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
 </… href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments>
 </div>' /* html or false to disable */
```

I already replaced this with the facebook comment (previously facebook like was there). A., nothing happens (maybe I need to implement other stuff on my website?) B., I am smart enough to know whatever URL I enter here, wont do, cause I need the URL to change dynamically whichever picture is viewed.

--Updated with comment for better view--

Comment: Well, what's the error you are running into? what have you tried?

Comment: I found in the prettyphoto javascript that is for the "social" stuff: social_tools: '<div class="facebook"><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments></div>' /* html or false to disable */ --- I already replaced this with the facebook comment (previously facebook like was there). A., nothing happens (maybe I need to implement other stuff on my website?) B., I am smart enough to know whatever URL I enter here, wont do, cause I need the URL to change dynamically whichever picture is viewed.

Comment: update your question instead of commenting because it's hard to read the code you typed.